# Excel to Latex code not working properly in overleaf

Tags: excel2latex

I'm trying to use a large analysis table in overleaf. And i'm using `excel2latex` but it does not seem to fit properly on the page. Following is the latex code. Can someone please help?
Thanks

```
\begin {table}[h]
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'ANOVA_10 VALUES_5519_mean'
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Demographic variables}} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Values}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{ANOVA}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Bonferroni \newline{}Correction\newline{}(0.005)}}} \\
\cmidrule{3-6}          &       & \textbf{df group} & \textbf{df residual} & \textbf{F} & \multicolumn{1}{p{6.25em}|}{\textbf{Pr(>F)\newline{}(0.05)}} &  \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{10}[20]{*}{\textbf{Gender}}} & HEDONISM & 1     & 5238  & 131.60 & \multicolumn{1}{p{6.25em}|}{<2e-16 ***} & <2e-16 *** \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & SELF\_DIRECTION & 1     & 5238  & 16.86 & \multicolumn{1}{p{6.25em}|}{1.04e-15 ***} & 1.04e-15 *** \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & STIMULATION & 1     & 5238  & 29.16 & \multicolumn{1}{p{6.25em}|}{6.96e-08 ***} & 6.96e-08 *** \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & SECURITY & 1     & 5238  & 0.84  & 0.358 & 0.358 \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & CONFORMITY & 1     & 5238  & 2.12  & 0.146 & 0.146 \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & TRADITION & 1     & 5238  & 5.94  & \multicolumn{1}{p{6.25em}|}{0.0148 *} & 0.0148 * \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & ACHIEVEMENT & 1     & 5238  & 2.01  & 0.157 & 0.157 \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & POWER & 1     & 5238  & 156.80 & \multicolumn{1}{p{6.25em}|}{<2e-16 ***} & <2e-16 *** \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & UNIVERSALISM & 1     & 5238  & 99.48 & 0.152 & 0.152 \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & BENEVOLENCE & 1     & 5238  & 2.05  & 0.700 & 0.700 \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{10}[20]{*}{\textbf{Age}} & HEDONISM & 2     & 5514  & 73.73 & <2e-16 *** & <2e-16 *** \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & SELF\_DIRECTION & 2     & 5514  & 166.50 & <2e-16 *** & <2e-16 *** \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & STIMULATION & 2     & 5514  & 305.40 & <2e-16 *** & <2e-16 *** \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & SECURITY & 2     & 5514  & 84.20 & <2e-16 *** & <2e-16 *** \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & CONFORMITY & 2     & 5514  & 133.20 & <2e-16 *** & <2e-16 *** \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & TRADITION & 2     & 5514  & 78.67 & <2e-16 *** & <2e-16 *** \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & ACHIEVEMENT & 2     & 5514  & 117.90 & <2e-16 *** & <2e-16 *** \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & POWER & 2     & 5514  & 48.05 & <2e-16 *** & <2e-16 *** \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & UNIVERSALISM & 2     & 5514  & 259.80 & <2e-16 *** & <2e-16 *** \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & BENEVOLENCE & 2     & 5514  & 54.72 & <2e-16 *** & <2e-16 *** \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{10}[20]{*}{\textbf{Ethnicity}} & HEDONISM & 3     & 5155  & 81.60 & <2e-16 *** & <2e-16 *** \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & SELF\_DIRECTION & 3     & 5155  & 96.47 & <2e-16 *** & <2e-16 *** \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & STIMULATION & 3     & 5155  & 66.69 & <2e-16 *** & <2e-16 *** \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & SECURITY & 3     & 5155  & 52.88 & <2e-16 *** & <2e-16 *** \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & CONFORMITY & 3     & 5155  & 29.95 & <2e-16 *** & <2e-16 *** \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & TRADITION & 3     & 5155  & 23.40 & \multicolumn{1}{p{6.25em}|}{4.9e-15 ***} & 4.9e-15 *** \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & ACHIEVEMENT & 3     & 5155  & 46.30 & <2e-16 *** & <2e-16 *** \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & POWER & 3     & 5155  & 1.78  & 0.149 & 0.149 \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & UNIVERSALISM & 3     & 5155  & 47.13 & <2e-16 *** & <2e-16 *** \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & BENEVOLENCE & 3     & 5155  & 32.16 & <2e-16 *** & <2e-16 *** \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{10}[20]{*}{\textbf{Education\newline{} level}}} & HEDONISM & 3     & 4722  & 2.95  & 0.031 & 0.031 \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & SELF\_DIRECTION & 3     & 4722  & 8.25  & \multicolumn{1}{p{6.25em}|}{1.78e-05 ***} & 1.78e-05 *** \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & STIMULATION & 3     & 4722  & 11.08 & 3.03e-07 *** & 3.03e-07 *** \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & SECURITY & 3     & 4722  & 2.68  & 0.045 & 0.045 \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & CONFORMITY & 3     & 4722  & 1.51  & 0.211 & 0.211 \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & TRADITION & 3     & 4722  & 5.24  & 0.001 & \cellcolor[rgb]{ .988,  .894,  .839}\textcolor[rgb]{ .612,  0,  .024}{} \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & ACHIEVEMENT & 3     & 4722  & 1.00  & 0.391 & 0.391 \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & POWER & 3     & 4722  & 0.12  & 0.948 & 0.948 \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & UNIVERSALISM & 3     & 4722  & 3.92  & 0.008 & 0.008 \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & BENEVOLENCE & 3     & 4722  & 0.78  & 0.680 & 0.680 \\
    \midrule
    \newpage
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{10}[20]{*}{\textbf{Income\newline{}level}}} & HEDONISM & 2     & 3856  & 2.34  & 0.097 & 0.097 \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & SELF\_DIRECTION & 2     & 3856  & 2.75  & 0.064 & 0.064 \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & STIMULATION & 2     & 3856  & 0.63  & 0.533 & 0.533 \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & SECURITY & 2     & 3856  & 1.28  & 0.279 & 0.279 \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & CONFORMITY & 2     & 3856  & 1.29  & 0.276 & 0.276 \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & TRADITION & 2     & 3856  & 0.65  & 0.525 & 0.525 \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & ACHIEVEMENT & 2     & 3856  & 0.85  & 0.429 & 0.429 \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & POWER & 2     & 3856  & 1.56  & 0.211 & 0.211 \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & UNIVERSALISM & 2     & 3856  & 1.49  & 0.225 & 0.225 \\
\cmidrule{2-7}          & BENEVOLENCE & 2     & 3856  & 0.25  & 0.777 & 0.777 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that). Also, format your code properly by putting it between triple inverted quotes. Thank you.

Comment: If it's more than a page, you'll want the longtable package.  See for example https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables#Multi-page_tables.  Also, I would recommend reading the booktabs documentation to make a nicer table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there are `>` and `<` in your table, it is recommended to use `xelatex` to run it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}
[
long,
caption={Add caption},
label={tab:addlabel}
]
{
colspec={Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]Q[c,m]},
rows={rowsep=2pt},
columns={colsep=2pt},
cells={font=\small},
column{1}={font=\bfseries\small},
row{1,2}={font=\bfseries\small},
cell{1}{1,2,7}={r=2}{},
cell{1}{3}={c=4}{},
cell{3,13,23,33,43}{1}={r=10}{},
cell{38}{7}={red9},
hline{1,3,13,23,33,43,Z}={.08em},
hline{2}={3-6}{.05em,leftpos=-1,rightpos=-1,endpos},
vlines={0.08em,dashed},
rowhead=2
}
{Demographic\\variables} & Values          & ANOVA    &             &        &               & {Bonferroni\\Correction\\(0.005)}\\
                         &                 & df group & df residual & F      & Pr(>F) (0.05) & \\
Gender                   & HEDONISM        & 1        & 5238        & 131.60 & <2e-16 ***    & <2e-16 ***\\
                         & SELF\_DIRECTION & 1        & 5238        & 16.86  & 1.04e-15 ***  & 1.04e-15 ***\\
                         & STIMULATION     & 1        & 5238        & 29.16  & 6.96e-08 ***  & 6.96e-08 ***\\
                         & SECURITY        & 1        & 5238        & 0.84   & 0.358         & 0.358\\
                         & CONFORMITY      & 1        & 5238        & 2.12   & 0.146         & 0.146\\
                         & TRADITION       & 1        & 5238        & 5.94   & 0.0148 *      & 0.0148 *\\
                         & ACHIEVEMENT     & 1        & 5238        & 2.01   & 0.157         & 0.157\\
                         & POWER           & 1        & 5238        & 156.80 & <2e-16 ***    & <2e-16 ***\\
                         & UNIVERSALISM    & 1        & 5238        & 99.48  & 0.152         & 0.152\\
                         & BENEVOLENCE     & 1        & 5238        & 2.05   & 0.700         & 0.700\\
Age                      & HEDONISM        & 2        & 5514        & 73.73  & <2e-16 ***    & <2e-16 ***\\
                         & SELF\_DIRECTION & 2        & 5514        & 166.50 & <2e-16 ***    & <2e-16 ***\\
                         & STIMULATION     & 2        & 5514        & 305.40 & <2e-16 ***    & <2e-16 ***\\
                         & SECURITY        & 2        & 5514        & 84.20  & <2e-16 ***    & <2e-16 ***\\
                         & CONFORMITY      & 2        & 5514        & 133.20 & <2e-16 ***    & <2e-16 ***\\
                         & TRADITION       & 2        & 5514        & 78.67  & <2e-16 ***    & <2e-16 ***\\
                         & ACHIEVEMENT     & 2        & 5514        & 117.90 & <2e-16 ***    & <2e-16 ***\\
                         & POWER           & 2        & 5514        & 48.05  & <2e-16 ***    & <2e-16 ***\\
                         & UNIVERSALISM    & 2        & 5514        & 259.80 & <2e-16 ***    & <2e-16 ***\\
                         & BENEVOLENCE     & 2        & 5514        & 54.72  & <2e-16 ***    & <2e-16 ***\\
Ethnicity                & HEDONISM        & 3        & 5155        & 81.60  & <2e-16 ***    & <2e-16 ***\\
                         & SELF\_DIRECTION & 3        & 5155        & 96.47  & <2e-16 ***    & <2e-16 ***\\
                         & STIMULATION     & 3        & 5155        & 66.69  & <2e-16 ***    & <2e-16 ***\\
                         & SECURITY        & 3        & 5155        & 52.88  & <2e-16 ***    & <2e-16 ***\\
                         & CONFORMITY      & 3        & 5155        & 29.95  & <2e-16 ***    & <2e-16 ***\\
                         & TRADITION       & 3        & 5155        & 23.40  & 4.9e-15 ***   & 4.9e-15 ***\\
                         & ACHIEVEMENT     & 3        & 5155        & 46.30  & <2e-16 ***    & <2e-16 ***\\
                         & POWER           & 3        & 5155        & 1.78   & 0.149         & 0.149\\
                         & UNIVERSALISM    & 3        & 5155        & 47.13  & <2e-16 ***    & <2e-16 ***\\
                         & BENEVOLENCE     & 3        & 5155        & 32.16  & <2e-16 ***    & <2e-16 ***\\
{Education\\level}       & HEDONISM        & 3        & 4722        & 2.95   & 0.031         & 0.031\\
                         & SELF\_DIRECTION & 3        & 4722        & 8.25   & 1.78e-05 ***  & 1.78e-05 ***\\
                         & STIMULATION     & 3        & 4722        & 11.08  & 3.03e-07 ***  & 3.03e-07 ***\\
                         & SECURITY        & 3        & 4722        & 2.68   & 0.045         & 0.045\\
                         & CONFORMITY      & 3        & 4722        & 1.51   & 0.211         & 0.211\\
                         & TRADITION       & 3        & 4722        & 5.24   & 0.001         & \\
                         & ACHIEVEMENT     & 3        & 4722        & 1.00   & 0.391         & 0.391\\
                         & POWER           & 3        & 4722        & 0.12   & 0.948         & 0.948\\
                         & UNIVERSALISM    & 3        & 4722        & 3.92   & 0.008         & 0.008\\
                         & BENEVOLENCE     & 3        & 4722        & 0.78   & 0.680         & 0.680\\
{Income\\level}          & HEDONISM        & 2        & 3856        & 2.34   & 0.097         & 0.097\\
                         & SELF\_DIRECTION & 2        & 3856        & 2.75   & 0.064         & 0.064\\
                         & STIMULATION     & 2        & 3856        & 0.63   & 0.533         & 0.533\\
                         & SECURITY        & 2        & 3856        & 1.28   & 0.279         & 0.279\\
                         & CONFORMITY      & 2        & 3856        & 1.29   & 0.276         & 0.276\\
                         & TRADITION       & 2        & 3856        & 0.65   & 0.525         & 0.525\\
                         & ACHIEVEMENT     & 2        & 3856        & 0.85   & 0.429         & 0.429\\
                         & POWER           & 2        & 3856        & 1.56   & 0.211         & 0.211\\
                         & UNIVERSALISM    & 2        & 3856        & 1.49   & 0.225         & 0.225\\
                         & BENEVOLENCE     & 2        & 3856        & 0.25   & 0.777         & 0.777\\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I was able to fix it